# Should TA work be listed in a CV for an internship in the industry?

Tags: cv, industry, teaching-assistant, internship

Personally, I didn't teach but helped the professor conduct a laboratory course throughout the semester.

It was also not a paid work but I volunteered.

Should something like this be omitted from an industry CV?

Having little to zero working experience, could it be of any interest to a company?

Comment: "I...helped the professor conduct a laboratory course throughout the semester...It was also not a paid work but I volunteered." Presumably you were paid by the University (perhaps as a PhD student), hence, this was a paid position and should be listed on your CV (under your duties as a PhD student).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you had some actual duties, this counts as experience and should be listed, especially given that you say you don't have very much additional experience.  You should also ask this instructor if he could be a reference.